# Let $p=x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Z}/3[x]$ . write down the multiplication table for $\mathbb{Z}/3[x]/(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $p=x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Z}/3[x]$ . write down the multiplication table for $\mathbb{Z}/3[x]/(p)$

[image]

sorry i don't know how to solve that's the reason i am not add any effort plesae any one help me

Comment: Can you at least tell me how many elements there are in this ring?

Comment: Before we can fill out the table, we need to know what the elements are; that's a good place to start.

Comment: @Bob Jones...since $x^2+1$ is irreducible so there are $3^=9$ elements right sir..

Comment: @ Kaj Hansen..sir there are 9 elements are there

Comment: @ Bob Jones.....can you expalin table please

Answer (score 0):

So we consider $x^2 + 1$ to be equivalent to $0$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.
So $x^2 \equiv -1 \equiv 2$. So all polynomials can be reduced to at most linear ones, by reducing $x^2$ and also higher powers using these equivalences. We have 3 options for constant terms, and $3$ for the coefficient of $x$, and for all those we have

$$(a + bx)(c+dx) = ac + (bc+ad)x + bdx^2 \equiv (ac-bd) + (bc+ad)x$$

Now you can make a table...(coefficients reduced mod $3$ of course)

Comment: ...sir i am not understand you logic can yo explain  more please ..thank you for time

Comment: @suresh If you don't understand it, go read up on how quotients work, e.g. What **exactly** are you missing?

Comment: ,,i am starting now. i am not understand can explain at leat one row of table

Comment: @suresh one row is always easy (with $1$ ) plus it's commutative so you only need the right upper half. Writing out the table is pointless, you just need to know how to compute products (which I gave a formula for).

Comment: ,,so first row is  $1, x,x^2$

Comment: @suresh it's a 9 by 9 table and $x^2 = -1$ remember?

Comment: second row is $x,2,1$ is it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73068/discussion-between-suresh-and-henno-brandsma).

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma...there are 81 elements right?